# Как получить данные из АЦП в Python

Tags: python

Имеется вектор `a` Numpy постоянно изменяющихся в реальном времени чисел в формате `np.float64`. Данные необходимо передать на ЦАП, затем с него на АЦП и обратно в вектор `b` в программу python. Есть советы как это сделать (желательно с минимально возможной задержкой)? В каком направлении двигаться? Буду благодарен любому совету.

Comment: Если нужно с минимальной возможной задержкой - то двигаться в сторону Си

Comment: А о каком устройстве вообще идёт речь?

Comment: @S.H. Марка оборудования (ЦАП/АЦП) пока не определена... Любой совет будет полезен для меня. Вообще исходное устройство USB-микрофон

Comment: Так всё будет зависеть от того, как написано `API` к конкретному устройству, что оно принимает на вход и отдаёт на выходе.

Comment: Но, несмотря на неопределенность марки оборудования - у Вас, скорее всего, известна платформа, на которой это будет запускаться: одно дело - это 64-разрядный "писюк" с полноценной операционкой (и вытекающими из этого граничениями - DMA там, прерывания, то-сё), а другое - хилый STM32, на котром нет OS, и куда влазит только микро-пайтон, зато - натоящий реалтайм и всё такое!

Comment: @S.H. будет работать на ПК в Windows 10, Python т.к. использую CUDA на GTX 1080 для скорости

Answer (score 1):

Неизвестно, какие данные принимает `API` на входе и какие отдаёт на выход, возможно ваш ЦАП/АЦП будет принимать на вход прямо данные `Numpy`. Но если нет, то `Numpy` легко преобразует данные в байты и обратно:

```py
import numpy as np

numbers_float = np.random.rand(10000)
numbers_bytes = numbers_float.tobytes()
numbers_back = np.frombuffer(numbers_bytes)
print((numbers_float == numbers_back).all())
# True
```

У меня в системе тип получился `numpy.float64`, но не везде может быть так, возможно нужно будет приводить к/указывать конкретный тип при преобразованиях.

Comment: Хороший совет! Прямо первое полезное предложение по такому неопределенному вопросу!

Comment: Я конечно дико извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, но как данные из вектора попадут в ЦАП?

Comment: @bluesky Мне самому интересно)  Я ж не знаю, что за ЦАП и какое у него API